# warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type buffer

Tags: c, winapi, buffer

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); i++) if(buff[i] = ' ') ++num;
char **parts[num];
char *p;
p = strtok(buff, " ");
int j = 0;
while(p != NULL)
{
         parts[j] = p;
         j++;
         p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

During compiling the warning was raised:

> assignment from incompatible pointer type, where parts[j] = p is.

What can I do?

Comment: `p` is a `char *` and `parts[j]` is a `char**`.

Comment: but I want a pointer array of pointers

Comment: A pointer to an array of pointers, you mean?

Comment: Yeah exactly, how can I do it?

Comment: But the way you use it strongly suggests that you really want an array of pointers to `char`: `char * parts[num]`.

Comment: You might like to change `if (buff[i] = ' ')` to be `if (' ' = buff[i])`, try to compile your code and then look at it again ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you would like to store individual tokens in an array. As is currently declared, `parts` is an array of pointers to pointers. That is not what you want for an array of C strings - you need to remove one asterisk:

```
char *parts[num]; // This requires at least C99
```

Note that `num` needs to start at `1`, not at `0`, because the number of tokens that you are going to get is one greater than the number of spaces that you will find in the string.

Once you do, your program would still need some fixing in the way it deals with results of `strtok`: you should *not* store results for use after the next call of `strtok`, because these results become invalid. Instead, you should make duplicates of tokens before storing them in the `parts` array:

```
parts[j] = strdup(p);
```

Comment: still crashes when I'm trying it

Comment: @OrrGoren Did you catch my last edit about `num` starting at `1`?

Comment: @OrrGoren No, that's not what I meant: you should change the assignment of `num` prior to entering the first `for(i=0;...)` loop of your program, the one not shown in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *parts[num];
```

you can declare a pointer to the array of pointers declared above like so:

```
char *(*ptr)[num] = &parts;
```

but you don't need this extra level of indirection to store an array of strings

Comment: you can take address of the array: `&parts`

Answer (score 0):

Do you use this line in your actual code?

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(buff); i++) if(buff[i] = ' ') ++num;
```

You are setting entire buffer to spaces. And setting `num` to `sizeof(buff)`

So, in other words this might not position you where you want:

```
 char **parts[num];
```